# Microsoft.XRM.SDK.dll upgrade

Tags: dll, dynamics-crm, crm

I have one small doubt regarding `Microsoft.Xrm.SDK.dll`. Recently I received an email from Microsoft saying they are turning off support for any `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll` version **less than `8.2`**.
I am using Dynamics CRM 2016 (App version: `8.1.1.1183`, DB Version: `8.1.1.1183`), and SDK client to connect to this CRM. This SDK client uses `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll v6.1.`
I want to know will it continue to work or do I have to make change in the code and upgrade the dll?
Thanks

Comment: Can you share the email content?

Comment: @jcjr - the only content which i can share is "Microsoft is turning off support for any Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll version less than 8.2."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably related to ACS deprecation (which is only applicable for online orgs):

See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2017/05/29/update-dynamics-crm-client-sdk-version-to-avoid-calls-to-acs/

> With the deprecation of Azure Access Control Service (ACS), you should
>   modify the SDK authentication code by removing all references to ACS.
>   Effective from Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online 2016 Update 1 (v8.1.1)
>   and Microsoft Dynamics 365 (v8.2), we removed Live ID support and ACS
>   dependencies on the server-side. It is required to update the
>   references in all client side components by updating the SDK.

For custom applications you need to make sure you have the **correct** version of the SDK.

> Custom Application(s) – If you have developed a Web/Windows/Console
>   application that is interacting with Dynamics CRM
>
> - Scan the folders on your server where the solution is running and look for: Microsoft.XRM.SDK.dll. If found, use the table given in the
>     [Team Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2017/02/01/dynamics-365-sdk-backwards-compatibility/) site to determine which version of the SDK you need to
>     download.
> - [Using the table](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2017/02/01/dynamics-365-sdk-backwards-compatibility), determine which version of .NET that you have deployed against, and confirm the version of Dynamics 365 CRM service
>     you are using. If you are uncertain which .NET version your solution
>     is using, contact your development or engineering teams.
> - Once you have determined the correct SDK version to use simply replace the Microsoft.XRM.SDK.dll found in /bin folder with the latest
>     version of the SDK dll.Replace Microsoft.XRM.SDK.dll with latest
>     version of SDK dll

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to go through the [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2017/02/01/dynamics-365-sdk-backwards-compatibility/)

Without knowing when & where (which CRM version your) project started & staying in 2016 now and what’s your future project plans (whether sustenance mode or stay current), could not comment on action.

As a general practice, do a pilot with an upgrade in separate copy/sandbox & see. Then plan for code Update & sdk upgrade in Live.